# OnMapReadyCallback not transmitted to parent fragment in nested multipane layout using Navhost

Tags: google-maps, android-fragments, android-architecture-navigation, android-nested-fragment, android-touch-event

I have Navhost which contains photo fragment and map fragment.
Map fragment is working when I use it alone, but when I try to integrate it in parent fragment I can scroll map but I cannot use any marks and other my custom options.

I do not want to re-implement map functionality inside parent fragment as it should work out of the box.
All ideas are appreciated.

To be on the same page I would maybe rephrase my question. If I take official example how can I make several maps on the screen simultaneously inside wrapping fragment with correctly working touch events and ability to replace them  and share data dynamically? (Official google maps example https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/maps-platform-101-android/#0 )

Answer (score 0):

My mistake was simply using original SupportMapFragment while I had to use my own fragment which implements OnMapReadyCallback and inflates layout containing SupportMapFragment.

(Could not solve it for a week and solved right after posting a question.)